# Tunnel into Sonicwall VPN while on Sonicwall wifi?

Tags: networking, vpn, sonicwall, wifi

I am able to hit my company's VPN while I am at home using a dedicated IP with no issue.

When I am at work, the VPN we use (a Sonicwall router/VPN/wifi access point), I can get outside internet fine, but am unable to connect to the VPN.

I know that the wifi puts me on a different subnet, and when I try to connect to the normal VPN IP it won't work, and a traceroute just times out.

Any suggestions?  Might there be an internal IP I need to hit while here at work?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but why are you trying to VPN into the network, when you are on the network?

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a rule setup in the Sonicwall appliance's ACL allowing vpn traffic from the wireless network to the Lan network, this is diabled by default.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I manage a sonicwall appliance here, and VPN has never worked when I've tried testing it behind the sonciwall device.  The only change you could really do on your end is to connect to an external connection that is off of the sonicwall's network.  Any other method that I can think of to try to address the issue you have would involve changing the configuration on the sonicwall device itself.  If there are resources you can't get to while on wifi, that may be intentional since wifi isn't as secure as a wired connection.  Your best bet would be to talk to whoever manages the appliance, explain what you are trying to do, and then they can see about coming up with a way to implement it.